# How to load the environment variables at boot time before X11 on Ubuntu Precise?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, environment-variables

Ubuntu Precise 64 bit, I'm facing a problem that I'm unable to solve and that I'll try to describe below:

I'm using a console mode program (let's say abc) that uses Go, NodeJS, Java and Scala.

In order for abc to work with these languages, I've to declare the following statements:

a) within `/etc/environment`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin"
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/scala-library.jar
```

b) within `/etc/login.defs`

```
ENV_SUPATH  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
ENV_PATH  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

c) a) within `/etc/sudoers`:

```
# env_reset

Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin"
```

Then, when I start abc from a terminal, all is fine and I can use any of the 4 languages described above.

However, if I put a script within `/etc/init.d` that starts abc during the boot process (i.e. before to start the GUI), using Java from abc still is fine, but using Go, NodeJS or Scala doesn't work anymore.

Then, I guess that during the boot process, the script within `/etc/init.d` that starts abc is executed before that the different environment variables set within `/etc/sudoers`, `/etc/environment` and `/etc/login.defs` are loaded.

So, my question is: how to force the environment variables to be loaded before that my script starting abc is launched?

Any help and advice on this topic would be truly appreciated.

---

Thanks again to Mark and Danila.

Below is the Danila's modified "abc" script file that I put within `/etc/init.d`

---

```
#!/bin/sh

##### EDIT: ADD THIS VARS DEFINITIONS:
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin" 
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/scala-library.jar
"ENV_SUPATH PATH"="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin"
"ENV_PATH PATH"="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin"
"Defaults secure_path"="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin"

##### EXPORT this VARS so they are accessible to children:"
export "PATH" "CLASSPATH" "ENV_SUPATH PATH" "ENV_PATH PATH" "Defaults secure_path"

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          abc
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: abc initscript
# Description:       This initscript starts and stops abc
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Fnux, fnux.fl at gmail dot com
# Version: 1.2
# Note: (edit ABC_PATH if abc isn't installed in /opt/abc)

NAME=abc
ABC_PATH=/opt/abc
START="-d"
STOP="-k"
VERSION="-v"
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
STARTMESG="\nStarting abc in deamon mode."
UPMESG="\n$NAME is running."
DOWNMESG="\n$NAME is not running."
STATUS=`pidof $NAME`
# Exit if abc is not installed
[ -x "$ABC_PATH/$NAME" ] || exit 0
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo $STARTMESG
    cd $ABC_PATH
    ./$NAME $START
    ;;
  stop)
    cd $ABC_PATH
    ./$NAME $STOP
    ;;
  status)
    if [ "$STATUS" > 0 ] ; then
      echo $UPMESG
    else
      echo $DOWNMESG
    fi
    ;;
  restart)
    cd $ABC_PATH
    ./$NAME $STOP
    echo $STARTMESG
    ./$NAME $START
    ;;
  version)
    cd $ABC_PATH
    ./$NAME $VERSION
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|status|restart|stop|version}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
:
```

---

Now, when executing this script (ie. `sudo service abc start`) I get the following error messages:

```
fnux@fx8150-1204-3:~$ sudo service abc start
/etc/init.d/abc: 4: /etc/init.d/abc: ENV_SUPATH PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin: not found
/etc/init.d/abc: 5: /etc/init.d/abc: ENV_PATH PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin: not found
/etc/init.d/abc: 6: /etc/init.d/abc: Defaults secure_path=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin: not found
/etc/init.d/abc: 7: export: ENV_SUPATH PATH: bad variable name 
fnux@fx8150-1204-3:~$
```

---

So, where am I wrong?

TIA for an explanation how to fix this script.

Comment: Rather than messing about with all that simply set (and export) the environment variables in the /etc/init.d script itself.

Comment: Thank you Mark, but I don't know how to do so. Could you please explain how to set and export the environment variables in the /etc/init.d script? I guess you're talking about my abc script that start the abc executable. If yes, how should I declare these environment variables. TIA and thanks again for the hint.

Comment: Well if init.d abc script kicks off all others apps where you need those env variables available if you export all those vars in your abc script they will get passed to all other kicked off apps(children processes)

Comment: So just do "export PATH=$PATH:whatever_path_you_need_to_append". Also the same with other variables you need to have to pass to children processes.

Comment: Thank you Danila, but I'm quite a newbee and I'm not sure how to set the Go and Scala environment variables within my /etc/init.d/abc script. I put this script in the next answer (to be readable).

Comment: well if within the init script you call your binaries jars or whatever, you can pass var from within abc script as -D PATH parameter, some binaries as they are being forked of your init.d script will inherit environment variables from the parent process which is your abc init.d script

Comment: In fact, I've just modified my original message to include the abc initscript file since I can't answer myself to my own question before the next 8 hours (I'm too young on this forum). ;)

Comment: your init script is quite bad, but even in this script you could add something like this: i will edit the script.

Comment: I will never ever claim that my script could be good or even fair since, as I said, I'm a newbee trying to learn Linux. So, thanks again for your precious advice and help.

Comment: I added an edit to your question. this is the link to a good bash tutorial: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Comment: OK Danila, I see what you did. I'll try that and will let you know tomorrow since I'm currently in Europe and it's already 3:15 AM. In any event, thank you so much for your help. BTW, do not hesitate to tell me why my script is so bad. Then I'll learn from your comment to correct this script and for future others. Thanks again. Cheers. ;)

Comment: there are just numerous things. read the link i gave you.

Comment: OK Danila, I've read the complete link you gave me and made the modifications that you said but now, I get the errors shown in the main message above. I guess it's a syntax problem but I don't understand how to fix it. TIA for your help. Cheers. ;)

Comment: **This is not a forum.** Please do not put garbage like "SOLVED" in your question title. To mark a question as solved, click the check mark next to the answer that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I found the problem: Never use double quotes (") for a VAR.

So, below is the right script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin" 
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/scala-library.jar
ENV_SUPATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin"
ENV_PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin"
export PATH CLASSPATH ENV_SUPATH ENV_PATH

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          abc
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: abc init script
# Description:       This init script starts and stops abc
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Fnux, fnux.fl at gmail dot com
# Version: 1.2
# Note: edit ABC_PATH if abc isn't installed in /opt/abc

NAME=abc
ABC_PATH=/opt/abc
START="-d"
STOP="-k"
VERSION="-v"
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
STARTMESG="\nStarting abc in deamon mode."
UPMESG="\n$NAME is running."
DOWNMESG="\n$NAME is not running."
STATUS=`pidof $NAME`
# Exit if abc is not installed
[ -x "$ABC_PATH/$NAME" ] || exit 0
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo $STARTMESG
    cd $ABC_PATH
    ./$NAME $START
    ;;
  stop)
    cd $ABC_PATH
    ./$NAME $STOP
    ;;
  status)
    if [ "$STATUS" > 0 ] ; then
      echo $UPMESG
    else
      echo $DOWNMESG
    fi
    ;;
  restart)
    cd $ABC_PATH
    ./$NAME $STOP
    echo $STARTMESG
    ./$NAME $START
    ;;
  version)
    cd $ABC_PATH
    ./$NAME $VERSION
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|status|restart|stop|version}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
:
```

Thanks for your help.

Hope this may help others.

Cheers. ;)